# Creating personal or joint broker account

Tags: united-states, taxes, stock-markets, non-resident

This is a follow up question to this question:

[Chances of paying U.S inheritance tax as a non U.S citizen](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/118708/chances-of-paying-u-s-inheritance-tax-as-a-non-u-s-citizen)

I am a nonresident alien and my wife is a US citizen who is not living in the US.

I want to open an account in Interactive Brokers to trade stocks. I am planning to buy only Vanguard's Irish index funds (VHVE, Small World cap index) in order to increase the distribution (not just American stocks like s&p) and also to pay less dividends tax.

Since I'm not buying American funds, is my wife's citizenship (or mine for that matter which is not American) affect my account at IB? What are the pros and cons of opening a joint account vs a personal lone account?

Comment: As a US citizen, your wife is required to file a US tax return on which she must declare her world-wide income. This is true regardless of where she resides, or to whom she is married. If you open a joint brokerage account in your name and your wife's name, then you need to figure out the taxation of the dividends since the money is coming to you jointly.

Comment: Meaning a single account is better or at least simpler?